# how to use float and margin together

Tags: html, css

I want to give background color to the `class='middle'` which is also background color of `lmiddle` and `rmiddle`, both `div` should be aligned horizontally.

I am unable to solve this problem. please help me.

```
<div class="middle">
  <div class="lmiddle">
      <h2>heading is here ???</h2>
          <p>something is here...something is here...
              something is here...something is here...
              something is here...something is
          </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rmiddle">
      <img src="dog_03.png" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a markup error, you need to close the class `.middle`

Comment: Could you post your CSS, or create Plunker on http://plnkr.co/ which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for styling use this

```
<style type="text/css">
        .lmiddle, .rmiddle{
            width:50%;
            border:thin solid #ccc;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            background:transparent;
        }
        .rmiddle{
            right:0;
        }
        .lmiddle{
            left:0;
        }
    </style>
```

and add a closing div to the end of your code

```
<div class="middle">
  <div class="lmiddle">
      <h2>heading is here ???</h2>
          <p>something is here...something is here...
              something is here...something is here...
              something is here...something is
          </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rmiddle">
      <img src="dog_03.png" />  
  </div>
</div>
```